# Compile apk with lower SDK than required

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, libgdx

I made a game using LibGDX (the latest version) in Android studio 3.1.2, to create the project, LibGDX asked for the Android SDK 27.0.3 (API 27). So I installed it. But I want people who use the app to be able to run it with the API 19 or higher.

I tried this (build.gradle file, android module)

```
buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
compileSdkVersion 19

[...]

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.rgs.demo"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

Is it possible to do what I want to do? If yes, can someone explain me how to do it?

Comment: `minSdkVersion 19` means it's runnable on API 19 and higher. But you really should set compiledSdkVersion to 27; it doesn't exclude older devices, and it allows you to use newer features on newer devices

Comment: It seem to work just fine, thanks